# Inject service inside a service inside a service in my Angular 2 application

Tags: angular, angular2-services

**Update: I overlooked a service, the problem actually is about a service that injects a service that injects a service. I updated the post.**

I am having a hard time injecting a service inside a service in my Angular 2 application, I am not sure if I am interpreting some concepts of dependency injection wrong.

My situation is as follows:
[image]
I have a parentcomponent called *app.component* that uses a *loginservice* to authenticate users, this service is bootstraped in the app bootstrapping process.

I also have a artist component that uses a *sharedservice*, this service is provided inside my parent component. I want the *loginService* also injected inside my *sharedService*, so I can logout a user is a certain action is triggered inside my sharedService.

Somehow, this always returns an error from my sharedService that my loginService is undefined. I thought that the following line should work to inject my loginService inside my sharedService:

```
constructor(@Inject(LoginService) private _loginService: LoginService,
    private _router: Router, private _http: Http) { }
```

_loginService still is undefined... Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?

As requested the relevant code snippits:

**bootstrap.ts**

```
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/router';
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/http';

import { LoginService } from './+login/login.service';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
  HTTP_PROVIDERS,
  LoginService
]);
```

**app.component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
....

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'sd-app',
    templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, SidebarMenuComponent, PAGINATION_DIRECTIVES, Growl],
    providers: [ArtistService,
        SharedService]
})
```

**artist.component**

```
import { Component, provide, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
....


@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    directives: [ FORM_DIRECTIVES, Confirm, RequestListComponent,
    QuotationListComponent, TOOLTIP_DIRECTIVES, SELECT_DIRECTIVES ],
    pipes: [ MapToIterablePipe, DayMonthYearTimePipe ],
    templateUrl: 'artist-detail.html'
})

export class ArtistComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(
        private _artistService: ArtistService,
        public sharedService: SharedService
    ) { }
```

**artist.service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { SharedService } from '../shared/shared.service';

@Injectable()
export class ArtistService {

    constructor(private _sharedService: SharedService) {
    }
```

**shared.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Headers, Http, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';

import { LoginService } from '../+login/login.service';

@Injectable()
export class SharedService {

    constructor(@Inject(LoginService) private _loginService: LoginService,
        private _router: Router, private _http: Http) { }

    logoutUser(objectType: string, objectID: string) {
        this._sharedService.logout();
    }
```

Comment: Why does your graphics show service name starting with lowercase first char while your constructor shows it with uppercase first character. It would be more helpful to see the actual code that the (nice) graphics you added.

Comment: I'll add my code in the post, I thought that this would make it more understandable :)

Comment: I think your understanding is correct but there has to be some error in your code.

Comment: Where do you provide and inject `SharedService`?

Comment: I oversaw a service, I updated a the post (it was actually a service in a service in a service). My SharedService is provided in the app component, it is injected in my ArtistService.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong. Maybe an import. Are you sure `+` in path doesn't cause issues? Can you try to reproduce in a Plunker?

Comment: I'll try to reproduce it!