# Angular 2 inject service into extended class(BaseRequestOptions)

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, angular

I have the following code that extends the `BaseRequestOptions` class:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class AppRequestOptions extends BaseRequestOptions {
    constructor(private serviceA:ServiceA) {       
        super();        
    }   
    merge(options?: RequestOptionsArgs): RequestOptions {        
        console.log(this.serviceA);
        //this.serviceA.myCustomMethod();
        return super.merge(options);
    }
}
```

When I reference `this.serviceA` the value is `undefined`. When I inject the same service into other services/components it is working as expected.

Here is the complete bootstrap code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrap }    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS  } from './routes';
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS, BaseRequestOptions, RequestOptions, RequestOptionsArgs, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { ServiceA } from './ServiceA';

@Injectable()
export class AppRequestOptions extends BaseRequestOptions {
    constructor(private serviceA:ServiceA) {       
        super();        
    }   
    merge(options?: RequestOptionsArgs): RequestOptions {        
        console.log(this.serviceA);
        //this.serviceA.myCustomMethod();
        return super.merge(options);
    }
}

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    HTTP_PROVIDERS,  
    ServiceA,
    { provide: RequestOptions, useClass: AppRequestOptions }
]).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

`ServiceA` declaretion:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class ServiceA {
    myCustomMethod() {
     
    }
}
```

I am using Angular version **2.0.0-rc.4**

I am not sure if it is because I am extending a class and marking it as `@Injectable()` ?

I have checked and the only related questions I can find are:

> [Inject service inside a service inside a service in my Angular 2 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37836376/inject-service-inside-a-service-inside-a-service-in-my-angular-2-application)
>
> [Angular 2: Inject Service to another service. (No provider error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37152608/angular-2-inject-service-to-another-service-no-provider-error)

**UPDATE**

Seems like it is related to a open bug : https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8925

Comment: Which version of Angular2 do you use?

Comment: @ThierryTemplier I am using 2.0.0-rc.4

Comment: AppRequestOptions isn't @Injectable.

Comment: Yup, pretty sure because AppRequestOptions isn't marked as Injectable. estus please make that your answer :)

Comment: @estus I have updated my code to mark it as Injectable and it's still not working.

Comment: The code in the question still doesn't show that.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer please see updated question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an open bug for this: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9758.

Whereas the metadata for dependency injection is correctly set, the element isn't provided to the class instance at the constructor level.

```
@Injectable()
export class AppRequestOptions extends BaseRequestOptions {
  constructor(private serviceA:ServiceA) {       
    super();        
    console.log(Reflect.getMetadata('design:paramtypes', AppRequestOptions));
    console.log(Reflect.getMetadata('parameters', AppRequestOptions));
  }

  (...)
}
```

See this plunkr for more details: https://plnkr.co/edit/hcqAfsI7u88jbjScq6m3?p=preview.

**Edit**

It will work if you use the `RequestOptions` class instead of the `BaseRequestOptions` one:

```
@Injectable()
export class AppRequestOptions extends RequestOptions {
  constructor(private serviceA:ServiceA) {       
    super();        
  }   

  (...)
}
```

See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/laP04kqUCOR5qbFgo0iM?p=preview.

Comment: seems like it is specifically related to this https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8925

Comment: Yes it's also work for me with Class RequestOptions instead of BaseRequestOptions ;-) I updated my answer accordingly...

Comment: Thanks, updating to extend  `RequestOptions ` solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is very similar to the question I answered here: [Injected dependency is undefined when extending BaseRequestOptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40294123/injected-dependency-is-undefined-when-extending-baserequestoptions/41578983#41578983)

When defining your provider also define the dependencies needed, so the object in your providers definition would look like:

```
{
 provide: RequestOptions,
 useClass: AppRequestOptions,
 deps: [ServiceA]
}
```