# Angular 2, Extending a class

Tags: typescript, angular

I'm trying to extend a method from inside [this](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-file-upload) Angular package.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Injectable  } from '@angular/core';
import { FILE_UPLOAD_DIRECTIVES, FileUploader } from 'ng2-file-upload';

@Injectable()
export class FileUploadComponent extends FileUploader {

  constructor(public _myService: MyService) {
    super(arguments);
   }

  onAfterAddingFile(file: any) {
    file.withCredentials = false;
  }
}
```

Inside of the `FileUploader` class, this is the item I'm wanting to extend:

```
export declare class FileUploader {
  ...
  onAfterAddingFile(fileItem: any): any;
}
```

I found [this](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-file-upload/issues/140), but I can't seem to get it to work. I'm needing to extend that class so that when a file is added to the FileUploader, it sets `withCredentials` to false, as this flag should not be true for my current needs.

Comment: You need to add the `@Injectable()` decorator if you want to use this class with DI. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38436658/angular-2-inject-service-into-extended-classprovider

Answer (score 3):

You can't extend a component since you won't inherit the metadata of the parent component class.

This article could help you to understand what is the problem:

- https://medium.com/@ttemplier/angular2-decorators-and-class-inheritance-905921dbd1b7