# Injected dependency is undefined when extending BaseRequestOptions

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection

I am extending `BaseRequestOptions` in Angular2 to add headers for each request. I also have a `Config` class that supplies key/value pairs based on the domain, which I need to inject into my derived class:

```
import { BaseRequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Config } from '../../config/configuration';

export class DefaultRequestOptions extends BaseRequestOptions {
  constructor(private config: Config) {
    super();

    Object.keys(this.config.api.headers).map((key) => {
      this.headers.append(key, this.config.api.headers[key]);
    });
  }
}
```

In my module, I am specifying the provider as such:

```
@NgModule({
  . . .,
  providers: [
    . . .,
    { provide: RequestOptions, useClass: DefaultRequestOptions }
  ]
})
. . .
```

The problem I'm having is that `this.config` is `undefined` in `DefaultRequestOptions`. I am also using the `Config` class as an injected dependency in other classes, so I'm confident it's working as expected, and if I manually set the values for `this.headers` everything works fine.

What am I doing wrong that would cause the config to be undefined in `DefaultRequestOptions`?

Comment: The answer to this question is about 3/4 the way through: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Provider classes don't require `@Injectable()` *unless* they require constructor parameters to be injected. In your case it does. This is why Angular recommends to *always* use it on your providers, whether or not you require injections. Maybe for this exact reason, where you forget, when it's needed.

```
@Injectable()
export class DefaultRequestOptions extends BaseRequestOptions {
```

---

**After testing**

It seems this still doesn't work. I've seen this problem is a result of extending a class that already uses `@Injectable()` (which `BaseRequestOptions` does). In this case, the parent constructor is called instead of the extending class'. If you extend `RequestOptions` instead (which is not decorated with `@Injectable()`) then it would work

```
@Injectable()
class DefaultRequestOptions extends RequestOptions {
  constructor(public config: Config) {
    super({method: RequestMethod.Get, headers: new Headers()})

    this.headers.append('data', this.config.data);
  }
}
```

Notice the `super()` call. This is all that [`BaseRequestOptions` does](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/http/src/base_request_options.ts#L182).

If you wanted to keep it the way it currently is, using `BaseRequestOptions`, then you could use a factory, instead of letting Angular create it

```
{
  provide: RequestOptions,
  deps: [ Config ],
  useFactory: (config: Config) => {
    return new DefaultRequestOptions(config);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll give that a try first thing when I get in.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually much easier than peeskillet's answer.  When defining your provider also specify the dependencies for that provider so it would look like:

```
providers: [
{
    provide: RequestOptions,
    useClass: DefaultRequestOptions,
    deps: [Config]
};
```